# How can i get thumbnails from my folder?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, thumbnails

I'm wondering that how to get thumbnails in UWP using C#

I want to get all thumbnail images of image files (gif, jpg etc) in my folder

I read quite codes about getting thumbnails and refered to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/thumbnails) and the other samples

But i couldn't fully understand the process with Xaml

Can you please tell me how to get thumbnail from my library folder?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have access to a folder through user selection with a `FolderPicker`.you can retrieve the thumbnails from the system. You can use the `GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync()` for that.
For instance:

```
private async Task<BitmapImage> GetThumbnail(StorageFile file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        StorageItemThumbnail thumb = await file.GetScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.VideosView);
        if (thumb != null)
        {
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            await img.SetSourceAsync(thumb);
            return img;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```